# How to use data types in Haskell after you defined them?

Tags: haskell, types

I defined a data `Suit` and a data `Value` for a deck of cards.  I also defined the type `Card` and type `Deck`.  But I have no idea how to use them.

```
data Suit = Club | Diamond | Heart | Spade

data Value = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight | Nine | Ten | 
  Jack | Queen | King | Ace

type Card = (Suit, Value)

type Deck = [Card]
```

Can someone give me an example of how to use the these?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a replacement for a tutorial or introductory textbook when taking the first steps toward learning a new language.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to add a few derived instances to your types.

```
data Suit = Club | Diamond | Heart | Spade
  deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Ord, Show)

data Value
  = Two | Three | Four | Five | Six | Seven | Eight
  | Nine | Ten | Jack | Queen | King | Ace
  deriving (Bounded, Enum, Eq, Ord, Show)

type Card = (Suit, Value)

type Deck = [Card]
```

Here are some decks.

```
royalFlush :: Deck
royalFlush = [ (Spade, v) | v <- [Ten .. Ace] ]

completeDeck :: Deck
completeDeck =
  [ (s, v) | v <- [minBound .. maxBound], s <- [minBound .. maxBound] ]
```

Here's a function to find all the clubs in a deck.

```
filterClubs :: Deck -> Deck
filterClubs = filter (\(s, v) -> s == Club)
```

With the help of the [`random`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random) package, we can pick a random card:

```
import System.Random

randomCard :: IO Card
randomCard =
  let r xs = (xs !!) <$> randomRIO (0, length xs - 1)
  in  (,) <$> r [minBound .. maxBound] <*> r [minBound .. maxBound]
```

Better yet, let's use the [`random-shuffle`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-shuffle) package, and now we can shuffle a deck:

```
import System.Random.Shuffle

shuffleDeck :: Deck -> IO Deck
shuffleDeck = shuffleM
```

Here's a function that tells you how many points each trick is worth for an undoubled bet in [bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_scoring#Contract_points).

```
import Numeric.Natural

points :: Suit -> Natural
points Heart   = 30
points Spade   = 30
points Club    = 20
points Diamond = 20
```